# cordova iOS connection object not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7

I dont know whether its happening only for me or for all ;I am using cordova 3.3 ;with iOS 7 ;
when I use the connection object its not returning anything.

```
function checkConnection() {
alert("a");
var networkState = navigator.Connection.CELL, states = {};

states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown';

states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet';

states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi';

states[Connection.CELL_2G] = '2G';

states[Connection.CELL_3G] = '3G';

states[Connection.CELL_4G] = '4G';

states[Connection.NONE] = 'None';

return states[networkState];

}
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    alert(checkConnection());

},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
    };
```

the thing is the alert in the device ready is working fine but not the other part;even the alert in the connection function is working fine but not returning anything. 
Also I don't find the console message displayed in the console.
I followed all the steps in [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var networkState = navigator.Connection.CELL, states = {};
```

to

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type, states = {};
```

Also add this to your states object:

```
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
```

What the documentation is stating about iOS is that it cannot return the specific cell connection, so it passes a generic cell connection if one is detected.